# mysql "LIKE" or EXACT against filter string

Tags: mysql

We have and upload functions on our webpage, and there we have a filter database that you can add things that the user must not be allowed to upload.

And the upload side we have a mysql query that was suppose to block upload if the name persist in the filter database.

Our query now is :

```
$DB->query("SELECT id FROM filter WHERE filter LIKE '%". $Properties['Title'] ."%'");

if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
    $Err = '[b]Cannot upload this![/b]';
    include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
    die();
}
```

Problem now is if we block : My.Dog.In.The.Ocean.My.HomeVid.mp4
Then it also blocks: My.Dog.In.The.Garden.Avi

We need the query only to block if the filter string exist in the name EXCATLY.

Any ideers on what to change so that it blocks correctly?

*Note: $DB->record_count = function to cover mysqli_num_rows

Ofcause, we got $Properties to be the properties of uploaded element, and thereby Title to to be the string title

Comment: Forgot to say. we block My.Dog.And.Me.In.The.Ocean it should block : My.Dog.And.Me.In.The.Ocean.Bla.bla.bla.bla

But not My.Dog.And.Me.In.The.Garden.bla.bla.bla.bla

Its much have the exact filter string somewhere in the title to be blocked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18291696/edit . Use this to edit your question yourself

Comment: Two things - 1) your code above is open to SQL-injection attacks, you should be using parameterized queries/prepared statements, 2) Give some examples of what does and doesn't match. Your statement "We need the query only to block if the filter string exist in the name EXCATLY." - that is what doing a like "%...%" will do (i.e. if "..." is anywhere in the file name.  But you seem to think it's doing something incorrectly - give the specifics.

Comment: As it is now if i have blocked : Peter.At.The.Beach.

Then i cant upload : Peter.At.The.Mall.Homevid.avi

And i should be able to because the string in the filter database is Peter.At.The.Beach, so only a titel with that exacth string in should be blocked. Like Peter.At.The.Beach.Home.mpg <- that one should be blocked.

Understand what i mean?

Comment: So when it dos the mysql query, then i searches filter efter the title to see if there is a exact string that matches something in the title name, and if it get 0 matches then allowed  upload, if it gets matches then deny upload

Answer (score 0):

LIKE shouldn't match the way you are saying:

```
mysql> select 'My.Dog.In.The.Ocean.My.HomeVid.mp4' like '%My.Dog.In.The.Garden.Avi%';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'My.Dog.In.The.Ocean.My.HomeVid.mp4' like '%My.Dog.In.The.Garden.Avi%' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                      0 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

So you probably have some other issue going on, like $Properties['Title'] not being set to what you think it is. Unless you are sanitizing the file title somewhere else, you also have a SQL injection vulnerability here. Someone uploading a file named `'; DROP TABLE filter#` would wreck your database.

Comment: Ill try and explain better.
Ive got a database called filter, in the database i got names that are not allowed to be uploadet.
How should i make a query that searches that filter database for if anypart of the long name that are in $Properties titel